# Can emacs commands be called from a shell script?

Tags: shell, commands

I have a directory `~/foo` that contains several `org` files. I'd like to use `htmlize` to convert each `org` file into an `html` file. Ideally this would be done with a shell script. Is there a way to make a shell script use `htmlize` to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following emacs lisp code saved in htmlize-script.el:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/htmlize/")
(require 'htmlize)


(defun htmlize-files-in-dir (dir)
  (htmlize-many-files (directory-files dir t ".org$")))
```

And then use the following command from a script:

```
emacs -Q -nw --eval "(progn (load-file \"/path/to/htmlize-script.el\") (htmlize-files-in-dir \"$1\"))" --kill
```

Call the script with `scriptname /path/to/org/files`.
This will shortly show up the textual frame as was pointed out in the comments of the answer of unhammer, if you want to avoid that you can run emacs as a server and use the following command:

```
emacsclient --eval "(progn (load-file \"/path/to/htmlize-script.el\") (htmlize-files-in-dir \"$1\"))"
```

Comment: This answer has really helped me. Thanks! Out of curiosity, how could I modify this to have a only operate on a single file? I think `htmlize-many-files` would be changed to `htmlize-file`. Would any other changes need to be made?

Comment: Using `htmlize-file` should work. I think you can just replace the `(htmlize-files-in-dir \"$1\")` with `(htmlize-file \"$1\")` in the script command and call the script with the filename.

Answer (score 8):

You can run `emacs --batch f htmlize-my-org --kill` where `htmlize-my-org` is a function you've written that runs htmlize on those files.

You can also pass files on the command line, e.g. `emacs --batch --insert ~/foo/file1.org -f htmlize-my-org --kill`

As a more complete example, here's a way to run `M-x delete-trailing-whitespace` on all files in a dir:

```
$ for file in ~/fixme/*; do 
      emacs -Q --batch --insert "${file}" -f delete-trailing-whitespace \
        --eval "(write-file \"${file}.fixed\")" --kill
  done
```

See `man emacs` (search for "batch") for more info.

Comment: Note that running htmlize from batch mode will result in less colorful output because it's reusing font-lock information and font-lock is disabled in batch mode...

Comment: Can you turn on font-lock in your `htmlize-my-org` function?

Comment: Well, not really. If you look at the sources of `font-lock-mode`, you'll see it deactivates the variable controlling whether it is turned on.  If you just use the function being run depending on that variable, it still doesn't seem to work, probably because it's using the "JIT" variant by default which only starts fontifying when used interactively and if you just define `noninteractive`, you get loads of other unrelated errors. So, to conclude, IME Emacs sucks for batch processing stuff.

Comment: What if you just run it without `--batch` then? From my man-reading and testing, what you lose is nice stdout/stderr, but that might not be important in this case.

Comment: That should work, the only annoyance is that Emacs would briefly flash a graphical or textual frame before quitting.  Another option would be using the daemon and client which avoids the flash.

Comment: If you run it without `--batch` the flickering becomes less of a problem when you don't start an emacs instance for every file so it will only flicker one time. See my answer for details.