# Can I use find to pass a list to emacs commands?

Tags: org-mode, bash, script

I'm trying to modify a script I got from an [old question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14947/can-emacs-commands-be-called-from-a-shell-script) of mine.

I have many `.org` files under many subdirectories of `~/foo`. I want to quickly run `htmlize` on each `.org` file. I have some elisp code

```
$ cat ~/htmlize-script.el
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/htmlize-20130207.1202/")
(require 'htmlize)
```

and my script is

```
$ cat ~/script.sh
find ~/foo -name "*.org" -exec emacs --eval "
(progn
  (load-file \"~/htmlize-script.el\")
  (htmlize-many-files \"{}\")
  )
" --kill \;
```

However, running this code gives the error

```
Wrong type argument: listp
```

What is the issue here?

Issuing `C-h f htmlize-many-files` returns

```
htmlize-many-files is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in `htmlize.el'.

(htmlize-many-files FILES &optional TARGET-DIRECTORY)

Convert FILES to HTML and save the corresponding HTML versions.

FILES should be a list of file names to convert.  This function calls
`htmlize-file' on each file; see that function for details.  When
invoked interactively, you are prompted for a list of files to convert,
terminated with RET.

If TARGET-DIRECTORY is specified, the HTML files will be saved to that
directory.  Normally, each HTML file is saved to the directory of the
corresponding source file.
```

Is the problem that the `find` command does not pass the right list to emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> FILES should be a list of file names to convert

So presumably you actually need `(htmlize-many-files (list \"{}\"))` in that shell script.